# Dynamically apply a key/value pair to an array in one go (within first definition)

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Imagine this situation:

```
$component = array(
    'type' => 'chimney',
    'material' => 'stone'
);
```

What i would like to do is to add a key/value pair to this array, if a certain condition is met.

```
$hasMetrics = true;

$component = array(
    'type' => 'chimney',
    'material' => 'stone',
    'metrics' => ($hasMetrics ? array('width' => 60, 'height' => 2000) : false)
);
```

While this could be used, it will always cause a key called 'metrics' in my array.

Of course, if i don't want that, i could use `array_merge()` to merge a second array with the first (the second being either an empty array or the desired key/value pair, depending on the condition).

But what i am longing to find out is if there is any way to define this array like above, while taking care of `$hasMetrics`, without the use of any other means (such as `array_merge()`) but purely in the actual (first and only) definition of this array.

Like this: (non-applicable, demonstrative example)

```
$component = array(
    'type' => 'chimney',
    'material' => 'stone',
    ($hasMetrics ? array('metrics' => array(
        'width' => 60,
        'height' => 2000
    )) : false)
);
```

(This, as i understand it, would generate two keys (`type` and `material` and then create one keyless value that is, itself, an array containing a key (`metrics`) and another array as value.)

Can anyone show me some proper approach? Perhaps there is some kind of PHP function available, with special properties (such as `list()` which is capable of cross-assignment).

**EDIT**

Perhaps some more clarification is needed, as many answers point out ways to go such as:

- Using a followup assignment to a certain key
- Filtering the generated array after defining it

While these are perfectly valid ways to extend the array, but i am explicitly looking for a way to do this **in one go** within the **one** array definition.

Comment: If there a reason you can't follow up your definition of `$component` with an `if()` statement? Example: `if($hasMetrics) { $component['metrics'] = ...; }`?

Comment: Not really. My code is purely hypothetic. I am in a similar coding situation and was wondering if there are ways to go about this. It doesn't necessarily mean i am bound to this without any choice of further potential solutions available.

Comment: Well, as the answers are pointing out, you can't do it within the array definition itself. You have to add it somehow (either like in my example above or by using a constructor function or object).

Comment: My question aims explicitly at finding out if it can be done the way i describe. If it cannot be done that way, that is alright. But i'll keep up the question for a while to see if there are ways. Over the years i have seen quite a many features in PHP that i never knew were there.

Answer (score 4):

Not with the array defenition itself. I would add it to the array if necessary:

```
if($hasMetrics) {
    $component['metrics'] = array('width' => 60, 'height' => 2000);
}
```

Comment: Thank You. But this is not what i am looking for. I am not looking for an alternative, i want to know **if** there is a way to do it within one array definition.

Comment: I'm sorry but i dont know of a way to do it how you want to have it.

Comment: No problem. Just trying to find out IF there is a way.

Answer (score 1):

```
$hasMetrics = true;

$component = array(
    'type' => 'chimney',
    'material' => 'stone',
);

if($hasMetrics){
     $component['metrics'] = array('width' => 60, 'height' => 2000);
}
```

Comment: Thank You, i will try to improve my question to clarify that this is not what i am looking for. I am looking for a solution that covers everything within the one array definition.

Answer (score 1):

**Try**

```
$component = array(
    'type' => 'chimney',
    'material' => 'stone',
    'metrics' => $hasMetrics ? array('width' => 60, 'height' => 2000) : ''
);
```

And after that

```
$component = array_filter( $component ); // remove if it has '' value
```

**OR**

```
  $component = array(
        'type' => 'chimney',
        'material' => 'stone',
    );


if($hasMetrics) {
    $component['metrics'] = array('width' => 60, 'height' => 2000);
}
```

Comment: I like this approach, thank you. But it is not what i am looking for (although i find it quite innovative indeed). However, performance-wise i must say that adding something first only to remove it later is (generally and if possible) something that should at all times be avoided.

Comment: But this is what you asking)

Comment: I was explaining and showing with/in my third code example what i aimed to achieve. Of course this is not the everyday question, so its totally fine if someone misunderstood it. No problem :)